# Removal of Spill Error in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I inserted the following formula into a cell:

```
=IF(G3:G5="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

Whereupon I was received with the two cells underneath appearing with an identical output, and once I removed the outputs of the cells below, it came up with a spill error. Any advice on how to remove this so called `#SPILL` error?

Comment: What are you trying to obtain with the formula, in words.  As written, it will return `Yes` or `No` depending on the contents of `G3:G5`  This is an array formula so will return a result for each comparison.  The `#SPILL!` error is because you have data in one or more of the cells to which these results would usually spill into.

Comment: Ok, I tried adding an @, and the spill error was resolved. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @TheQuantumObsession,, I don't think that this formula returns #Spill error,, I do believe that U are using Excel 365,, also the formula U are using should an Array formula,, and will return YES if all cells in G3:G5 does have YES !!

Comment: @RajeshS In what ways does Excel 365 benefit over Office 2019?

Comment: @TheQuantumObsession,, nothing special but few like Dyanamic Array Command ,, new Graph & command like Textjoin ,, Switch ,, basics are similar.

Comment: Alright... is it necessary for me to switch over to Office 2019 so that the formula for calculation is correct?

Comment: **What are you trying to obtain with the formula, in words.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to test:

if you want to test if **all the values** in `G3:G5` are *"Yes"* then use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G3:G5,"Yes")=3,"Yes","No")
```

if you want to test if **any of the values** in `G3:G5` are *"Yes"* then use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(G3:G5,"Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

if you want to test **each item** in `G3:G5` and you are using Excel 365 then use the "spill-able":

```
 =IF(G3:G5="Yes","Yes","No")
```

[image]